# C++: Program crashes when loop condition is met

Tags: c++, class, while-loop, crash, conditional-statements

I have a program that creates objects from two different classes depending on user input. If the user is a student, an object of the Student class will be created where the student will enter the classes they are taking. I have a `while` loop that asks the user if they want to enter another class after each time they enter a class. If the person types `n`, which is the condition that should end the loop, the program halts with `exit code 11`:
[image]

This should not be the case. There is more lines of code after the while-loop, and the program should not end after the loop ends. Here is the function with the while loop in question:

```
void createStudent (char student_name[], int student_age)
{
    Student student;

    student.setName(student_name);
    student.setAge(student_age);

    char courses[8];
    char course_loop = ' ';
    int count = 0;

    cout << "What courses are you taking? "
        "(Enter course prefix and number with no spaces):\n\n";

    while (tolower(course_loop) != 'n')
    {
        cout << "Course #" << count + 1 << ": ";
        cin.ignore();
        cin.getline(courses, 9);
        //student.sizeOfArray(); // Increment the array counter if addCourse reports that the array was not full
        student.addCourse(courses, count);

        cin.clear();

        if (student.addCourse(courses, count))
        {
            cout << "\nHave another course to add? (Y/N): ";

            cin.clear();

            cin.get(course_loop);
        }
        else
        {
            cout << "You have exceeded the number of courses you're allowed to enter. Press any ENTER to continue...";
            cin.ignore();
            course_loop = 'n';
        }

        count++;
    }

    cout << student;
    student.printCourseNames();
}
```

Here is the rest of the program:

```
// main.cpp
//-----------------------

#include <iostream>
#include "Person.h"
#include "Student.h"
using namespace std;

void createStudent(char [], int);
void createPerson(char [], int);

int main()
{
    char name[128], student_check;
    int age;

    cout << "Please state your name and age: \n\n"
         << "Name: ";
    cin.getline(name, 128);
    cout << "Age: ";
    cin >> age;

    cout << "\n\nThanks!\n\nSo are you a student? (Y/N):";
    cin.ignore();
    cin.get(student_check);

    switch (student_check)
    {
        case 'y':
        case 'Y':
            createStudent(name, age);
            break;
        case 'n':
        case 'N':
            createPerson(name, age);
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}

// createStudent function with while-loop posted above comes after this in main.cpp

// student.h
// ------------------

#include "Person.h"
#ifndef PA2_STUDENT_H
#define PA2_STUDENT_H


class Student : public Person
{
    public:
        Student();
        bool addCourse(const char*, int);
        void printCourseNames();
        void sizeOfArray();

    private:
        const char* m_CourseNames[10] = {0};
        int array_counter;
};


#endif

// student.cpp
//------------------

#include <iostream>
#include "Student.h"

using namespace std;

Student::Student() : array_counter(0) {}

void Student::sizeOfArray()
{
   array_counter++;
}

bool Student::addCourse(const char* course, int  index)
{
    if (index < 9)
    {
        m_CourseNames[index] = course;
        return true;
    }
    else if (index == 9)
        return false;
}

void Student::printCourseNames()
{
    if (array_counter != 0)
    {
        cout << ", Courses: ";

        for (int count = 0 ; count < 10 ; count++)
            cout << m_CourseNames[count] << " ";
    }
}
```

I am using CLion as my IDE, if that helps.

Comment: What does your `<<` overload look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a function that can send a `Student` object to an output stream like `cout`. The way that this is accomplished is by defining a function like this:

```
ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const Student& student)
{
  os << "Name: " << student.name << ", Age: " << student.age << ", Courses: " << student.m_CourseNames;
  return os;
}
```

This function allows you to use the `<<` operator to send data to an output stream, like `cout`, from your `Student` class. It takes the output stream as one argument, and the student as the other. It prints the student's information, and then returns the output stream. This is so that you can chain the operator in order to print multiple pieces of information at once.

Comment: I have actually commented out the line `cout << student` and I get the same error message. Showing that the operator overloading is not the cause.

Answer (score 1):

EDIT:  The error associated with that return relates to the buffer.

Your input buffer `char courses[8]` is not large enough to handle the input from `cin.getline(courses, 9)` and that is causing an overflow on the `cin` buffer.  The `cin.clear()` hack is recovering the input stream to allow input for `cin.get(course_loop)`, but the exception is still unhandled when the function tries to return.

Change `char courses[8]` to `char courses[10]` (to match the `m_CourseNames` array in `Student`) and it should work properly.

Updated code:

```
void createStudent(char student_name[], int student_age)
{
    Student student;

    student.setName(student_name);
    student.setAge(student_age);

    char courses[10];
    char course_loop = ' ';
    int count = 0;

    cout << "What courses are you taking? "
        "(Enter course prefix and number with no spaces):\n\n";

    while (tolower(course_loop) != 'n')
    {
        cout << "Course #" << count + 1 << ": ";
        cin.ignore();
        cin.getline(courses, 9);
        cin.clear();

        //Removed the duplicate addCourse() call
        if (student.addCourse(courses, count))
        {
            student.sizeOfArray();  //Needed for printCourseNames() functionality
            cout << "\nHave another course to add? (Y/N): ";

            cin.clear();

            cin.get(course_loop);
        }
        else
        {
            cout << "You have exceeded the number of courses you're allowed to enter. Press any ENTER to continue...";
            cin.ignore();
            course_loop = 'n';
        }

        count++;
    }

    cout << student;
    student.printCourseNames();

    return;
}
```